# OpenAS2 server configuration to establish a connection to SAP-ICH AS2

Tags: ssl, mtls

I previously configured the OpenAS2 server to connect to another AS2 server over HTTP.

Now I need to configure the OpenAS2 server to connect to the SAP-ICH AS2 server over HTTPS.

SAP-ICH said my certificate should be an mTLS certificate, I don't know much about certificates, and I needed clarification on what is necessary.
Is this a special certificate, or is it a configuration in OpenAS2?

I really appreciate any help you could give me. Thanks.